# JSON string serialization ( to camel case ) and deserialization (from snake case )using Jackson

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, json-deserialization

I am trying to deserialize a json string to POJO and then serialize it back to json string using Jackson, but in this process I want resultant json string to have changed key values.

e.g. input json string:

```
{"some_key":"value"}
```

here is what my POJO looks like

```
public class Sample {    
    @JsonProperty("some_key")
    private String someKey;         
    public String getSomeKey(){
        return someKey ;
    };
}
```

When I serialize it again I want json string to be something like this

```
{"someKey":"value"} .
```

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to do  deserialization  by renaming   setter functions according to what is the input json string .

```
class Test{
    private String someKey;
    // for deserializing from field "some_key"
    public void setSome_key( String someKey) {
       this.someKey = someKey;
    }


    public String getSomeKey(){
        return someKey;
    }
}
```

Comment: While this technically works, your method names do not follow Java bean naming conventions (See Section 8.8 in http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/beans.101.pdf). This may lead to compatibility issues with other frameworks and if your work will be maintained by other developers, may lead to confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to pull this off by defining a creator for deserialization and then let Jackson do its default behavior for serialization.

```
public class Sample {    
    private final String someKey;

    @JsonCreator
    public Sample(@JsonProperty("some_key") String someKey) {
        this.someKey = someKey;
    }

    // Should serialize as "someKey" by default
    public String getSomeKey(){
        return someKey;
    }
}
```

You may need to disable `MapperFeature.AUTO_DETECT_CREATORS` on your `ObjectMapper` for this to work.